# Отзывы в 1C Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, cms, 1с

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в 1С-Битрикс стандартными средствами создать страницу с отзывами, которые смогут добавлять неавторизованные посетители, выставляя оценку. А после модерации админом они будут публиковаться.

В гугле нашел советы по добавлению инфоблоков и модерацию через документооборот. В настоящее время пробую выполнить задачу на демо-версии.

Answer (score 0):

Решение данной задачи много, вот один из примеров,

Добавить компонент "веб форма" и настроить поля, как вам хочется.

[Документация](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/service/form/form_edit.php)